# When we say a body is at high potential compared to the other, what can we interpret from this and why flow of electrons takes place?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

When we say electron flow from low potential to high potential when connected, what is the reason behind it. I am bit confused whether it is due to the excess of +ve charge on one body compared to the other. Please help in clarifying my doubt.

Comment: If current is flowing then it is not electrostatic. Can you clarify? Do you perhaps mean direct current instead of electrostatic? Or are you perhaps talking about the direction of the E field rather than the flow of charges?

Comment: Yeah actually you got me, I am talking about why do flow of charge take place . I will edit the question thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two bodies have different potentials, there is inevitably non-zero electric field between them (because $\phi_1-\phi_2 = \int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r}$, regardless of the choice for the path of integration). When you connect the two bodies with a conducting wire, this field will make the electrons move thus causing charge transfer, i.e. electron flow.

Answer (score 0):

It can be excess of + charges, but also the higher potential has less negativ charges compared to the lower